# Switch the keyboard language with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a multi-lingual database and am trying to make it so that the correct language is typed in the correct fields by using the "on current" event.  Presently, the users use Alt+Shift until the language appears in the task bar.  The languages are English, Hebrew, Arabic & German.  The users are fluent typists in the languages.  Constantly Alt+Shifting to select the correct language for each field slows down data entry dramatically.

I have searched the internet for VBA code to do this.   The closest I can find is "Sendkeys" which works in part by turning off & on Scroll Lock for autohotkeys which is only used for Hebrew vowel pointing, but I am unable to figure out how to select the keyboard language via VBA code.

Sample code for the Hebrew Name search button:

```
Private Sub btnHebCustomerSearch()
  SendKeys "{scrolllock}", True
    Me.FilterOn = False
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acFirst
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFind
  On Error Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do these help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.TextBox.KeyboardLanguage and https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/any-idea-how-to-change-system-keyboard-lenguage-with-vba.193030/ and https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-change-system-keyboard-language-with-vba.html

Comment: And https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d121f068-3f39-4fe8-9801-9542fb5dbb53/any-idea-how-to-change-system-keyboard-language-with-vba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a ton of web resources on this topic with Bing search "Access VBA switch keyboard language".

Use API function:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ActivateKeyboardLayout Lib _
"user32.dll" (ByVal myLanguage As Long, Flag As Boolean) As Long

'define your desired keyboardlanguage
'find your desired language at http://www.trigeminal.com/frmrpt2dap.asp

Private Const MKD = 1071 'macedonian keyboard language layout
Private Const eng = 1033 'english(united states)keyboard language layout

Private Sub A_Enter()
Call ActivateKeyboardLayout(MKD, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub A_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
Call ActivateKeyboardLayout(eng, 0)
End Sub
```

Untested, code from https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/any-idea-how-to-change-system-keyboard-lenguage-with-vba.193030/

Probably should declare the API function as Public and place it in a general module instead of behind a form. The Const declarations are not needed if intrinsic language code constants are used. View a list in VBA object browser. Type MsoLanguageID in the Search box and click Search button. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.languagesettings

Comment: The "http://www.trigeminal.com/frmrpt2dap.asp" to get your language code is now 404.   I found another website that had it though:  https://www.pdshop.com/locale-id-lcid-code-list-currency-date-kb-21/

Comment: As already noted, language code can be determined by viewing list in VBA object browser. Instead of using number, reference intrinsic constant, such as msoLanguageIDEnglishUS. If you want to know the number, type this in VBA immediate window: `?msoLanguageIDEnglishUS`.

Comment: @June7 - Consider 32/64 bit differences in current versions. - C.f. [Change keyboard input language .. in UserForm](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0c8f80b2-5084-4dba-b272-6797620f84a3/automatically-change-keyboard-input-language-when-set-focus-to-textbox-in-excel-userform?forum=exceldev)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that finally worked, thank you June7 for your help, you led me in the right direction:

```
Option Compare Database
    
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ActivateKeyboardLayout Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal mylanguage As Long, flag As Boolean) As Long


    Private Const Heb = 1037
    Private Const Eng = 1033
    Private Const Ger = 1031
    Private Const Grk = 1032
    Private Const Yid = 1085
    


Private Sub Text2_Enter() 'Hebrew Keyboard Layout
  
    Call ActivateKeyboardLayout(Heb, True)

End Sub

Private Sub Text2_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
  
    Call ActivateKeyboardLayout(Eng, True)

End Sub
```